# "No access token in response" error, while trying to access to Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, gspread

I trying to working with Google Sheet by using Python

Following the guidance from this site:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html
Including steps:

1. Go to the Google APIs Console.
2. Create a new project.
3. Click Enable API. Search for and enable the Google Drive API.
4. Create credentials for a Web Server to access Application Data.
5. Name the service account and grant it a Project Role of Editor.
6. Download the JSON file.
7. Copy the JSON file to your code directory and rename it to
   client_secret.json

Here is what I did so far

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IypqDnLKKR-IX1oOwCuTejBQ-RFq87K9rqSF6GpSyn4/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=109125393303568297837']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('test_xlsx').sheet1
```

However, I got this result errors

> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response.',
> {'id_token'..}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats not a google scope. this is the list of valid google [scopes#sheets](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets)

Even the tutorial you are following says to use the following scope.  Without including the correct oauth scope you font have access.

> scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

Comment: I am using the scope you said, but then i got 'gspread.exceptions.APIError (Request had insufficient authentication scopes)'. I added client_mail to the users on my google sheet tho... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, using the scopes from the tutorial, so I tried several from [scopes#sheets](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#sheets) suggested by DaImTo, until it eventually worked.
For me it was `scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']`